# eslint src/** --fix fails to find any matches

Tags: node.js, eslint

I installed ESLint globally using `npm i -g eslint`

In another SO thread I found that a path argument needed to be passed to the CLI in order to use `--fix` (it wasn't working on its own).

```
owner@G700:~/cp/foreignSentenceRepeater$ eslint src --fix

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.4.0

No files matching the pattern "src" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

owner@G700:~/cp/foreignSentenceRepeater$ eslint src/** --fix

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.4.0

No files matching the pattern "src/classes" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

`src` is definitely there and interestingly, the folder `classes` is a subfolder of `src`, even though I didn't explicitly mention it.

```
owner@G700:~/cp/foreignSentenceRepeater$ ls
audioCourse             node_modules       sentences.txt
compiled                package.json       silences
configuration.json      package-lock.json  src
googleCredentials.json  readme.md          tsconfig.json
```

Anyone know what the mistake is?

#### Update 1

A comment suggested trying a local install:

```
owner@G700:~/cp/foreignSentenceRepeater$ npm i -D eslint
npm WARN foreign_sentence_repeater@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ eslint@7.4.0
updated 1 package and audited 919 packages in 14.824s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4695 vulnerabilities (4693 low, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

owner@G700:~/cp/foreignSentenceRepeater$ node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js src/** --fix

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.4.0

No files matching the pattern "src/classes" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in prior comment I've been taught it's better to install packages as dev dependencies in case you ever intend to have calibration. Based on your command you could try:

```
npm run -- --fix
```

but it would be better to run it as a script, such as:

```
"scripts": {
   "fixer":"eslint --fix --ext .ts ."
}
```